# Performing a SUM over nested Foreign Key relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, postgresql

I have some tables roughly like so:

```
Client:
   id
   name

Employee 
   id 
   name

Email
   id
   to : Client [ForeignKey]
   from : Employee [ForeignKey]

EmailStats (Tracks the stats for a particular single email)
   id
   email : Email [OneToOne]
   curse_words : 10
```

**What I want to do:** I want to fetch *all* the employees that have written at least one email to a single client, along with the number of times they've cursed in any of their emails to that single client, i.e. for a particular `Client` return

```
[
    ('name' : 'Paul', 'total_curses' : 255),
    ('name' : 'Mary', 'total_curses' : 10),
]
```

**What I've tried:**

My understanding of SQL is quite weak as I'm used to using ORM's. I'm having trouble understanding how the normal retrieval of `Employees` links into the counting of the curse words. Here's what I've done (be kind!):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
    SELECT SUM(EmailStats.curse_words)
    FROM EmailStats
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT Email.id
      FROM Email
      INNER JOIN Employee
          ON Email.from = Employee.id
      WHERE Email.to = 5 // Assuming 5 is the client's id
    ) filtered_emails ON EmailStats.email = filtered_emails.id                
) AS 'total_curses', Employee.name
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Email
   ON  Email.from = Employee.id 
WHERE Email.to = 5 // Assuming 5 is the client's id
ORDER_BY 'total_curses'
```

This isn't working - it seems to fetch the correct `Employees` (those who have sent to the `Client`) but the curses count seems to be the total for all emails to that `Client` instead of just those curses from that `Employee`.

I've got a feeling that I'm gravely misunderstanding something here, so if anyone could provide an example of how to succesfully go about this I'd appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Not constructive, but what kind of company do you work for? Cursing at your clients? LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to group the result of joining your tables:

```
SELECT   Employee.name, SUM(EmailStats.curse_words) total_curses
FROM     Email
  JOIN EmailStats ON EmailStats.email = Email.id
  JOIN Employee   ON Employee.id      = Email.from
WHERE    Email.to = 5
GROUP BY Employee.id
ORDER BY total_curses DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT em.name, sum(s.curse_words) AS total_curses
FROM   employee em
JOIN   email e ON e.from = em.id
LEFT   JOIN emailstats s ON s.email = e.id
WHERE  e.to = $the_one_client
GROUP  BY em.name
ORDER  BY total_curses DESC;
```

I use a LEFT JOIN to make sure, because there does not seem to be a guarantee, that a matching row in `emailstats` actually exists.